# Cypress cy.tick() not forwarding time the second time it is called

Tags: javascript, cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

I have been reading the docs about `cy.clock` and using it with the component testing setup. But I seem to be doing something wrong here

```js
 it.only('shows an estimate on when it is ready (fulfilled)', () => {
    const now = new Date()
    cy.clock(now)

    mount(
      <ResizeWrapper>
        <CartProvider>
          <PaymentSucceededMessage />
        </CartProvider>
      </ResizeWrapper>
    )

    // Time left
    cy.contains('10 min', { matchCase: false }).should('be.visible')
    cy.tick(1000 /*ms*/ * 60 /*sec*/ * 1 /*min*/ + 300 /*ms*/)
    cy.contains('9 min', { matchCase: false }).should('be.visible')
    //  Something breaks here 
    cy.tick(1000 /*ms*/ * 60 /*sec*/ * 1 /*min*/ + 300 /*ms*/)
    cy.contains('8 min', { matchCase: false }).should('be.visible') // FIXME: The test does not work but the real life version does
  })
```

[image]

the implementation (for now) goes like this

```js
  const [minutesLeft, minutesLeftSet] = React.useState<number>(10)


  React.useEffect(() => {
    let timer
    if (minutesLeft > 0) {
      timer = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(new Date())
        minutesLeftSet((minutesLeft) => minutesLeft - 1)
      }, 1000 /*ms*/ * 60 /*sec*/ * 1 /*min*/)
    }

    return () => {
      if (timer) clearTimeout(timer)
    }
  }, [minutesLeft])
```

The console only shows 1 print of the `new Date()`...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for the same reason you often need to use the callback form of useState setter, e.g `minutesLeftSet((minutesLeft) => minutesLeft - 1)`, you also need a beat in the test to allow React hooks to process.

So, this works

```
const now = new Date()
cy.clock(now)

mount(
  <ResizeWrapper>
    <CartProvider>
      <PaymentSucceededMessage />
    </CartProvider>
  </ResizeWrapper>
)

// Time left
cy.contains('10 min', { matchCase: false }).should('be.visible')

cy.tick(1000 /*ms*/ * 60 /*sec*/ * 1 /*min*/ + 300 /*ms*/)
cy.wait(0)                                                      // yield to React hooks
cy.contains('9 min', { matchCase: false }).should('be.visible')

cy.tick(1000 /*ms*/ * 60 /*sec*/ * 1 /*min*/ + 300 /*ms*/)
cy.wait(0)                                                      // yield to React hooks
cy.contains('8 min', { matchCase: false }).should('be.visible')
```

Comment: This was the missing piece! Thank you very much.

Comment: Note: If I wish to move multiple minutes ahead I have to it in a loop to "beat" the hooks to kick in. `for (let n of new Array(8)) {cy.tick(1000 /*ms*/ * 60 /*sec*/ * 1 /*min*/).wait(0)}`